# simulating kinect sensor in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, kinect, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use the input from a kinect in simulation. I use ROS and therefor I think the best way is to use gazebo for simulation. Is there a way to simulate the kinect input data in gazebo?

Thanks for help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9792/simulating-kinect-sensor-in-gazebo/) by [Stefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/452/stefan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2011-04-21

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a Gazebo BlockLaser plugin which is able to simulate point cloud producing sensors (but there's no RGB value per point available easily AFAIK). See http://www.ros.org/doc/api/gazebo_plugins/html/group__GazeboRosBlockLaser.html. I added such a block laser to a erratic_robot for testing, the working xacro macro I used is here:
http://pastebin.com/F5Jamf78
Note that I had to make quite a few changes to how it was used in the API doc to make it work. Also note that it's performance isn't too good, so simulating a 640x480 point cloud or such will probably result in a severe slow down.

Luckily, there's work in progress regarding this topic, for some info see:

http://answers.ros.org/question/715/how-can-i-speed-up-simulation-in-gazebo
In the long answer there, Kevin Watts talks about changes to Gazebo for efficiently making depth camera data available.

http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/Simulating-RGB-D-sensors-in-Gazebo-td2518418.html
Basically same topic as this thread, only on the mailing list. There's also a link to the related ticket on trac.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2011-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-02-01**:
Hi, nice answer. you say the performance isn't too good, but what about the point cloud ?
Is it accurate ?

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-02-01**:
Also, the first link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you use the SVN branch for "kt2_simulator" (referenced above by Stefan), you can use the "gazebo_ros_wge100" plugin to simulate an RGBD camera. You can look in the package "kt2_pr2_defs" for information on how to configure a URDF/Gazebo model entry for the camera. The camera will publish camera info, images, disparity, and points2.

The changes in that branch will be merged in to trunk soon. I don't think the gazebo_ros_wge100 camera plugin follows the same topic name conventions as a Kinect, but it should be easy to solve by remapping.

---

Originally posted by [watts](https://answers.ros.org/users/99/watts/) with karma: 584 on 2011-04-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3